# How to pass columns of arrays in input (for keras rnn classification )

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Here is my sample dataframe

```
FROMLOC=['Toronto, Ontario, M9L 1P1','Toronto, Ontario, M9L 1P1','Toronto, Ontario, M9L 1P1','Toronto, Ontario, M9L 1P1','Toronto, Ontario, M9L 1P1']

TOLOC=['Milton, Ontario, L9T 5G5','Milton, Ontario, L9T 5G5','Milton, Ontario, L9T 5G5','Milton, Ontario, L9T 5G5','Milton, Ontario, L9T 5G5']

FROMTIME=['2019-07-03 18:31:08','2019-07-19 21:12:59','2019-07-26 19:50:40','2019-05-15 19:57:10','2019-05-14 13:23:07']

TOTIME=['2019-07-03 19:32:59','2019-07-19 22:33:37','2019-07-26 21:43:52','2019-05-15 21:28:57','2019-05-14 14:06:34']

TRAILERID=['H2','S4','S4','S45','S450']

FROMLAT=[53.763957,53.763972,53.763952,53.772897,53.773765]

FROMLONG=[-79.544993,-79.54482,-79.544573,-79.533958,-79.535332]

TOLAT=[53.537842,53.537748,53.537707,53.537698,53.535849]

TOLONG=[-79.905845,-79.905917,-79.905813,-79.905807,-79.908035]

latlist=[[50.986705, 50.986702, 50.98666, 49.16529,  49.165335, 49.165285],[50.986705, 50.986702, 50.98666, 49.16529,  49.165335, 49.165285],[50.986705, 50.986702, 50.98666, 49.16529,  49.165335, 49.165285],[50.986705, 50.986702, 50.98666, 49.16529,  49.165335, 49.165285],[50.986705, 50.986702, 50.98666, 49.16529,  49.165335, 49.165285]]

longlist=[[-113.95529,  -113.955237, -113.955197, -122.943097, -122.942958, -122.942997],[-113.95529,  -113.955237, -113.955197, -122.943097,-122.942958, -122.942997],[-113.95529 , -113.955237, -113.955197, -122.943097, -122.942958, -122.942997],[-113.95529,  -113.955237, -113.955197, -122.943097, -122.942958, -122.942997],[-113.95529,  -113.955237 ,-113.955197, -122.943097, -122.942958, -122.942997]]


data={'FROMLOC':FROMLOC,
     'TOLOC':TOLOC,
     'FROMTIME':FROMTIME,
     'TOTIME':TOTIME,
     'TRAILERID':TRAILERID,
     'FROMLAT':FROMLAT,
     'FROMLONG':FROMLONG,
     'TOLAT':TOLAT,
     'TOLONG':TOLONG
    }

sampledf = pd.DataFrame(data)

sampledf['latlist']=latlist
sampledf['longlist']=longlist
```

How to pass latlist and longlist columns as features in training data for keras RNN Classification